# simple to use ruby gem with date & time event calendar with month view

Tags: open-source, web-apps, software-development, web-development, ruby-on-rails

Any recommendations for a simple to use ruby gem with date & time event calendar with month view? The gem will ideally enable app users to select a date and time for their upcoming event and be saved to database (postgresql) via active record.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this easily with the jQuery Date picker. https://github.com/jquery-ui-rails/jquery-ui-rails provides an example in the readme file of how to use it.